# On an inequality between functions of observations of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let $Y$ be a random variable that has probability density $p$ and assume we can extract a sample $\{ Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n \}$ of arbitrary dimension from it.

Is is true that, for a big enough $n$, the majority of the realizations $Y_i$ will be such that
$$p(Y_i) > \tilde{p}( Y_i )$$
for any other probability density $\tilde{p}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take, for example, $p(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)$ and $\tilde{p}(x)=c^{-1}\cdot 1_{[0,c]}(x)$ for some $c\in(0,1)$. Then $\mathsf{P}(p(Y)<\tilde{p}(Y))=c$ which can be arbitrary close to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Question: if $c=1$  then $p = \tilde{p}$, how is it possible that $P(p(Y) < \tilde{p}(Y) )= 1$ ?

Comment: That's why I assume that $c<1$.

Comment: Also for $c\in (0,1]$, $\mathsf{P}(p(Y)\le \tilde{p}(Y))= c$.

Comment: What I meant is that as $c$ gets close to 1 the two probability densities become nearly identical so it seems strange that for $c$ close to 1 we would have $\mathsf{P}(p(Y)<\tilde{p}(Y))=c $.

Comment: The alternative pdf is still higher on [0,c].

Comment: Thanks! got it! would the statement be true instead if $\tilde{p}$ had to have the same support as $p$?

Comment: It won't work neither.